# SQL Server - Update field in all table records, using a field from the same table and values from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this scenario:

Table `Territory`

```
ID (int) - CODE (varchar) - NAME (varchar)
```

Data:

```
1 - GB - UNITED KINGDOM
2 - GB - ISLE OF MAN
3 - GB - NORTHERN IRELAND
4 - PT - PORTUGAL
5 - DE - GERMANY
6 - DE - HELGOLAND ISLAND
```

Table `Rules`:

```
ID (int) - TERRITORY_CODES (varchar) - TERRITORY_IDS (varchar)

1 - 'GB,PT' - NULL
2 - 'DE,PT' - NULL
```

I know the second table should not be like this, but I have no option to change it.

I want to fill the column `TERRITORY_IDS` with the IDs from the table `TERRITORY` separated by comma. For example:

Table `Rules`

```
ID (int) - TERRITORY_CODES (varchar) - TERRITORY_IDS (varchar)

1 - 'GB,PT' - '1,4'
2 - 'DE,PT' - '5,4'
```

There are several IDs for each territory code, but I want only one ID for each territory table, it could be the first one, doesn't matter.

Comment: On what basis you need to update data?

Comment: You should ***never ever*** store multiple values (comma-separated or otherwise) in a single database column. This violates even the **first normal form** of database design, and will cause you endless grief and hassle down the road. You have a **relational database** - use its features to your advantage, don't kludge on some comma-separated value in a single column mess on top of this ....

Comment: marc_s is right: don't do this. If you properly normalize your model, you will have a **lot** less problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is a *Bad Idea*. It is a good thing that you recognize this is a bad Idea. But for those reading this question and do not understand why it is bad, this violates the [First normal form (1NF) principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Which is all columns should be atomic, meaning that they hold 1 and only 1 value.

Lets get to the nuts and bolts on how to do this [Coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to the rescue.
Since I do not know why `'gb,pt'` and `'de,pt'` are grouped that way I didnt wrap this in a [Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to go through the whole table. But you can easily wrap this in a cursor and do the entire table contents for you.

```
DECLARE @TERRITORY_Ids varchar(100)

SELECT @TERRITORY_Ids = COALESCE(@TERRITORY_Ids+ ', ', '') + 
  Id
FROM table_terrytory
WHERE code  in ('gb','pt')

INSERT INTO table_rules
SELECT 'gb,pt',@TERRITORY_Ids
```